# How do I specify the correct import in tests?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I use **pytest**. I have a "kernel" folder in the root of the project in which the file is located "ecommerce.py"
Full path "./kernel/ecommerce.py" I have a unit test that should test this file it is in the path: "./test/test_ecommerce.py"
How do I correctly specify the import of a file "ecommerce.py" in the test file?

```
project_root/
    ├── kernel/
    │   └── ecommerce.py
    └── test/
        └── test_ecommerce.py
```

My attempts boiled down to the following:

```
from ..kernel.ecommerce import Ecommerce
```

and

```
from kernel.ecommerce import Ecommerce
```

and

```
os.path.dirname('/full/path/root_dir_project')
from kernel.ecommerce import Ecommerce
```

Despite the fact that the IDE sees the module correctly, py test itself cannot determine the kernel

```
ImportError while importing test module '/full/path/root_dir_project/kernel/test/test_ecommerce.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
kernel/test/test_ecommerce.py:7: in <module>
    from ..kernel.ecommerce import Ecommerce
E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Thanks! - oddly enough, the advice on the link worked after several attempts!

Comment: There are a few ways of arranging your code and tests and it can take a bit of coercion to get everything working together.  Generally worth the up front investment to get things running conveniently so they keep getting used.